# Does $2^n \bmod n$ ever repeat?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Title basically says it all, but...

Is it known whether the sequence generated by $2^n \bmod n$ is periodic as $n$ traverses the natural numbers?

Just for some flavor, the first 50 elements:

```
{0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4,
 2, 4, 2, 4, 8, 0, 2, 10, 2, 16,
 8, 4, 2, 16, 7, 4, 26, 16, 2, 4,
 2, 0, 8, 4, 18, 28, 2, 4, 8, 16,
 2, 22, 2, 16, 17, 4, 2, 16, 30, 24,
   ...}
```

Comment: I don’t know, but I would guess no, because I would expect the sequence to be unbounded.

Comment: This sequence appear on the list of integer sequences as http://oeis.org/A015910. It is conjectured that this sequence takes on every value but $1$. The much weaker statement that it takes on arbitrarily high values would be enough to disprove periodicity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$a_n=0$ iff $n$ is a power of $2$.  This is obviously not periodic.

Comment: All that means is that the eventual period, if one exists, must be a power of 2, right?

Comment: The gap between zeroes gets twice as long every time they occur.  So there will never be a period.

Comment: Right, iff not if.

Comment: Several good answers, but I gotta go with this one. Duh.

Answer (score 9):

If the sequence be periodic, there should exist $M$ s.t. $\forall n,2^n\,mod\,n<M$.

Choose $k$ s.t. $2^k>M$. Choose big prime $p>2^k$.

Let $n=pk$ then $2^n\equiv 2^k$ mod $p$. Thus, $2^n\,mod\,n\ge 2^k$. (contradiction)

Answer (score 7):

It's easy to prove that $2^{3^n} \equiv  3^n-1 mod(3^n)$. So if you consider the sequence $x_{n}=(2^{3^n} \equiv 3^n-1 
  mod(3^n))$ it's divergent to infinity, and assumes infinite distinct values. So the sequence can't be periodic.